# How to count number of cells greater or less than 0 (zero) between two dates in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice-calc

I have spent a couple of hours trying to find a way to achieve this, but I'm stuck. Please help!

**What is the formula to count number of cells greater or less than 0 (zero) between two dates in Excel?**
For example:
In the following extract there are 4 occurrences greater than 0 and 2 less than 0 between 4/26 and 4/28

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYDs5.png)

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Please provide some screenshots so that we can have a basic idea about what ur worksheet look like.

Comment: Updated the question with a screenshot

Comment: See Gary's answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dates in column **A** and values in column **B**, try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A:A>=DATE(2020,5,11))*(A:A<=DATE(2020,5,21)*(B:B<>0)))
```

for a date range from May 11<sup>th</sup> through May 25<sup>th</sup>:

[image]

**NOTE:**

1. assumes real dates and not text values
2. will work for both UK & US date formats

Comment: Thank you! This works! But, I want to be able to get the date from a cell instead of typing it into the formula manually. For example: ...A:A>=DATE(C1) instead of ...A:A>=DATE(2020,5,11). This didn't work when I tried. Any suggestions please?

Comment: @alien250  Very, very, close!  ............ **A:A>=C1** rather than **A:A>=DATE(2020,5,11)** .....................just be sure the dates are REAL!

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much for your time and sharing knowledge!

Comment: I too want to make Gary my teacher ;)

Answer (score 0):

You would use a `COUNTIFS()` Presuming your list of dates is in column A and your list of numbers is in column B and the date range is greater than 13/03/2020 but less than the 20/03/2020 then the formula would be:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,">13/03/2020",A:A,"<20/03/2020",B:B,"<>0")
```

Comment: I tried this before posting my question. Didn't work for me. Returns zero

Comment: Check your date column is actually formatted as a date (i.e. if you click the cell and look at the formula bar does it contain a date like `26/04/2020` or just say `Apr 26`) also check numbers are formatted as numbers. I tested this formula prior to posting and it definitely works.

Comment: Gary's Student's formula worked pretty well. Thank you for your time!

Comment: This formula actually did work! I had to use it as follows: =COUNTIFS(A:A,">0",B:B,">="&M4,B:B,"<="&N4). M4 and N4 are the cell locations of dates. Hope this helps somebody